# How to filter parent nodes, and then filter child nodes, without parents being affected by children filter? Neo4j 3.5

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of `Author` nodes. An `Author` node is the single parent of multiple `Book` nodes.

Step: 1) I want to filter authors by name. (Eg. author.name CONTAINS 'e')

Step: 2) Once I have this filtered list of authors, I want to filter each of these author's books by name. (Eg. book.name CONTAINS 'the')

Desired output: (Let's image Oscar Wilde didn't write any books with 'the')

[image]

My problem is that, after Step (2) *all authors that don't have a book with 'the' but **DO** have an 'e' in their name are **discarded*** - Like (in this example) Oscar Wilde

I tried:

```
MATCH (author:Author) WHERE (author.name CONTAINS 'e')
WITH author

MATCH (book)<-[:WROTE]-(author) WHERE (book.name CONTAINS 'the')

RETURN author, book
```

and

```
MATCH (author:Author) WHERE (author.name CONTAINS 'e')
WITH author

MATCH (book) WHERE (book.name CONTAINS 'the') AND ((book)<--(author))

RETURN author, book;
```

I would use a `WHERE EXISTS { MATCH ()...` subquery but this doesn't exist on Neo4j 4.0 and I'm using 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OPTIONAL MATCH` for the books, so that failure to find a suitable book for an `author` still allows that `author` to be returned.

For example:

```
MATCH (author:Author) WHERE author.name CONTAINS 'e'
OPTIONAL MATCH (book)<-[:WROTE]-(author) WHERE book.name CONTAINS 'the'
RETURN author, COLLECT(book) AS books;
```